# Auto Belt Width Algorithm

Tags: brute-force, subset-sum, bin-packing, simulated-annealing, knapsack-problem

I would really appreciate some comments about this practical problem.

**Quick description.** 
I have a variable number of links that can be used to make up a given belt width.  The question is, how many of each link.
Selection criteria:  it is better to use longer items.

**Example.** 
Let's say we want to create a belt width,
W = 1024.0
One of the models has the following link lengths:
L = [34.0, 65.0, 96.0, 126.0]

The question is, how many of each link to make the width.

Here is a few approaches I have tried.

**1. Greedy (select longest 1st to satisfy criteria)**
c = [0,0,0,8]
where c is the count of each item.
This leaves a gap of 16.0 and I can't fit even 1 of the smallest items.
Greedy is easy but not good.

**2. Selection loop**
Not too easy, I think that this is a difficult problem.
I have tried many strategies: filling with small items then removing them sequentially to fit the next size up.

**3. Knapsack method**
Not really appropriate because this is based on a given number of items.

**4. Subset sum problem**
This is a sub-class of Knapsack but I have not been able to get it working.

**5. Bin Packing problem**
It sounds similar but I couldn't get it to apply to my problem.

**6. Brute force (random selection)**
Strangely, this one finds many exact matches.
I use a simple polynomial of the count as a rating.
rating = n[0] + n[1]**2 + n[2]**3 + n[4]**4 + ...
One of the solutions from brute force is
[4, 0, 4, 4] giving exactly 1024.
The problem is, this method often comes up with a different selection so it is not ideal.

**7. Exhaustive search**
Not practical because there are too many choices.

**8. Simulated Annealing**
From the success of brute force, this looks like a good alternative.
Can someone point me to a simple example (please not another traveling salesman).

**9. Genetic and particle swarm**
Not sure about these.

Now, I am stuck and frustrated.
Is there a direct algorithm that can be used for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if I understand the problem correctly, you need to choose x1 objects of length 34, x2 objects of length 65, etc., etc., such that the sum of all these objects is equal to W, but there is a bias towards the longer objects (in this case, 126.0 would be the most favored object).

I suppose you could make an objective function that is like this:

f(x1,x2,..,xn) = b1*x1*L1 + b2*x2*L2 + ... + bn*xn*Ln - p*(W - x1*L1 + x2*L2 + ... + xn*Ln)^2

Where b1 thru bn are biases on those objects (positive numbers are favorable, negative numbers mean the object is disfavored), L1 thru Ln are the lengths of those objects, and p is a penalty for not being exactly W (if it must be exactly W, p is inf.)

(We could also put it in matrix form as f(X) = b^T*X*L - p*(W - I^T*X*L)^2, where b and L are vectors, X is a square diagonal sparse matrix of x1, x2, ..., xn I is a vector of 1's, and T is transposition.)

So the objective then it maximize f by searching over the n-tuple set of integers x1, x2, ..., xn.

*whew* Ok, now I think I understand the problem. :)

This is an integer programming problem of some sort, but I don't think it exactly qualifies as a quadratic-integer programming problem. Perhaps someone else knows what it is.

I've been studying and experimenting with simulated annealing a lot in my research. It usually can solve these types of discrete optimization problems easily. You can probably just use a linear or logarithmic temperature schedule for this problem.

If you only have a few objects though, with no intent on wide-scaling, then brute force would probably be fine. But if you are going to be doing this on hundreds or thousands of objects, then genetic algorithm, particle-swarm, or simulated annealing would probably be smart ideas. To the best of my knowledge, it is not really possible to know which optimization heuristic will work the best (e.g. find the result of desired accuracy in a satisfactory time frame) a priori.

I do not know enough about the other solution methods to provide comment.

Comment: In retrospect, you should just drop the penalty term if the chain length must be exactly W; solution will be practically impossible if p is inf.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I have done quite a lot of experimenting with different methods and in this case, the exhaustive search is not such a bad method. If you are interested, I did make some notes of my progress here... dl.dropbox.com/u/18869118/Articles/Optimum%20Search/index.htm